# datatype of prompt values in javascript in if else condition

Tags: javascript

```
let num1=prompt('Enter a num1:');
let num2=prompt('Enter a num2:');
if(num1 > 2)
 document.write("num1 is greater num2");
else
 document.write("num1 is less num2");
```

here, what is the type of num1 and num2 variable
if it is String datatype,so how it is comparing

Comment: `num1 > 2` and `num1 > num2` are very different things; if that's a typo (I assume it is) it'd be good to fix it because it changes the nature of the comparison.

Comment: It's referred to as type coercion. Read more about it here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I am assuming that you meant to write `if(num1 > num2)`. If this is not the case, refer to what @DaveNewton and @Ludolfyn mentioned about type coercion

Yes, it will return the variables with the type of string. However, it will compare them by the ordinal value of the characters, which will lead to unexpected (or rather expected, if you know how it works) results i.e. "15" will appear to be less than "4". Take a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and notice that the code for "1" (49) is less than the code for "4" (52), which will cause this.

You should first cast them to ints using `Number.parseInt(num1)` and then compare:

```js
let num1=Number.parseInt(prompt('Enter a num1:'));
let num2=Number.parseInt(prompt('Enter a num2:'));
if(num1 > num2)
 console.log("num1 is greater num2");
else
 console.log("num1 is less num2");
```

*However*, if the user enters a string which does not contain only digits (unless all of the digits are at the beginning of the string), this will return `NaN`, so be sure to check for that case with the `Number.isNaN` function

Comment: `"15" > 4` returns `true`--the order of the comparison matters, so it's best to either be explicit about how expressions have their operands coerced, or be less ambiguous in the description. I think the OP has a typo in their post which may have led to the confusion.

Comment: @DaveNewton we are talking about comparing two strings, not a string and a number. `"15" > "4"` will return `false` not `true`

Comment: @DaveNewton ah wait I see what you mean. Yeah I assumed OP was trying to compare `num1` and `num2`, especially since the `document.write` statements refer to comparing the two

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice it was probably a typo until after I commented--I'm sure you're right in your assumption.